# Installing Windows while saving Ubuntu data

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, windows

[image: My hardrive partition]

This is the situation I'm in: I want to intall Windows 10 from a pendrive without losing my 400 GB of data on my HDD. How would I do that?

Comment: Use gparted to shrink ext4 partition leaving whatever space you think you need, but not too small. Then be sure to boot Windows installer in UEFI boot mode. it will not install in BIOS boot mode to gpt partitioned drive and if forced will erase drive by converting to MBR(msdos) partitioning. No matter what else be sure to have good backups.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.